# What does "end stackable" package mean for a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, packages

What is the manufacturer trying to say when they say "end stackable" here? They don't seriously mean vertically stacking the DIPs on top of each other in a tower and soldering the leads do they?

[image]

Comment: Suggests to me that the package ends are short enough to allow placement on a constant (2.54mm?) pin pitch. Check that on the dimension drawing.

Comment: @user_1818839 Package info was not on the datasheet. In separate documents the HVMDIP-4 has a pin spacing of 0.100" x 0.300"~0.425"

Comment: Page 1 of most data sheets usually bends the truth or stretches the imagination in one or two directions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means you can put them side by side, and e.g. two of them next to each other would fit in the same footprint as a standard DIP-8.

Though the datasheet for the IRFD113 doesn't seem to include outlines of the package, looking at another part in the same package, the [IRFD120](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91128/sihfd120.pdf), reveals that the package is a max of 5.00 mm wide, just under 200 mils. This means that you could put two (or more) of them adjacent to each other on a 0.1" grid, such as on perfboard.

[image]

This is in contrast to other DIP outlines, which may protrude too far out each end to fit like this; two normal DIP-6s, for instance, might not fit in a "DIP-12" socket; you'd have to use a DIP-14 socket (which is more common anyway) and skip the middle pins. See for instance [this part](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/4n324n33-1767045.pdf) from the same manufacturer; its DIP-6 package has a body length of 8.6 mm (about 340 mils), so the pin spacing to mount two next to each other couldn't be uniform--else the two would intersect.

It's not really a feature that's relevant for high-performance designs, but for the early stages of prototyping, working on perfboard or stripboard, it might be marginally useful.

Answer (score 6):

Searching hard enough on the Vishay website, I find that the HVMDIP package is just less than 0.197 inch long, so these parts can be placed side-by-side in a standard 0.1" x 0.3" DIP socket without interference.